# Chrysler Voyager 1997 - How to run defrost without automatic switch on the AC?

Tags: ac, chrysler, defroster

Is it possible to run defrost without automatic using the switch on the air conditioning?

If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Agree with @vini_i - there is a reason the A/C runs with the defrost. It dehumidifies the air (from your breath) so the inside of the windows don't frost on the inside. Not all vehicles do this (obviously those without A/C won't). Feel sorry for those who don't have this feature.

Comment: You are right, AC defrost windsceen very fast. But when I travel on the road 5-6 hours I would like to have at this time a regular supply to the windscreen - no air conditioning. I think regular supply barely be enough to keep the windshield dry during his time. When I wanted to use the air conditioning - then I push myself AC button. My goal is to preserve the possibility of full MANUAL control over the ac, also during defrost. Is it possible?

Comment: On most vehicles, **it is not an option**. Leaving this as a comment because I'm not sure in your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, it is meant to operate this way. That being said, many of the vehicle specific online forums talk about how to disable it, to allow manual control. Searching, I didn't find a way to do that for your generation Voyager. For the prior generation, it was possible to disassemble and modify the HVAC control.

No one has reported a way to do this on the Chrysler minivan fan club forum, but it [has been discussed](http://forum.chryslerminivan.net/showthread.php/6437-Defeat-A-C-on-defrost)

Comment: Couldn't you unplug the AC coil? It's the plug on the back of the compressor....? And when u want to run AC just plug it back in..? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's always possible to disable it by disconnecting the clutch. But what some people look for is a way to conveniently run windshield defrost without the A/C compressor running. Because while dehumidifying with the A/C makes defrosting work better, sometimes you don't need max effectiveness, and it would be nice to be able to leave it on low without the constant A/C drag on the engine. This is especially true in vehicles where the A/C load on the engine is perceptible. Disconnecting the A/C clutch means you can't easily turn it on when you do need maximum effectiveness.